# AWS Network Load Balancer sending Traffic to Multiple Subnets

Tags: amazon-web-services, load-balancing, amazon-elb, aws-fargate

I have a Network Load Balancer exposed to the public internet with a listener of 80 and 443. The network load balancer has 2 subnets subnet-A and subnet-B. I have a target group for the port 443 traffic and for the port 80 traffic. The target groups has successfully registered the IP's of the Fargate service I have running and is connected. The issue I am facing is that when I make a request to my NLB via DNS it is only working about 50% of the time.

This is because when the request do the lookup of the A record for the NLB DNS is has 2 records, which make sense as the NLB has 2 public subnets.

The problem if I make my request and the DNS lookup returns the wrong IP, I get a timeout.

What I am missing so that the traffic get routed correctly?

**EDIT**

Yes both routes are pointing to the internet gateway, attached screenshot

[image]

No, I have cross zone load balancing turned off. It sounds like I need to turn on "cross zone load balancing" correct? Is that the only option to get this to work? I have a screen shot of the set up

[image]

I was looking at this link [AWS Load Balancing](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/prescriptive-guidance/latest/load-balancer-stickiness/subnets-routing.html) and it shows that it distributes the traffic to either subnet but maybe I am misreading it.

Comment: Is the default route on both of those subnets pointing to the Internet Gateway?  Did you enable [cross-zone load balancing](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticloadbalancing/latest/network/network-load-balancers.html#cross-zone-load-balancing)?

Comment: @Michael-sqlbot please see edits, I have answered questions there and posted my current settings

Comment: "DNS lookup returns the wrong IP": what exactly is a "wrong IP"? Do your internet clients query public A record for the NLB and can't connect to one of the IP addresses it returns?

Comment: @Quassnoi, wrong IP isn't the correct term. The DNS A records for the load balancer has 2 IPs one for each subnet. If my service is running on subnet B but the IP address of subnet A is returned during the DNS lookup, I get a timeout cause the request doesn't get routed to the other subnet.

Comment: @iqueqiorio: I'm still confused. Do you have targets in one availability zone but NLB in two?

Comment: Also, what does "IP address of subnet A is returned during the DNS lookup" mean? Are your clients public or not? Is your NLB public? (you said yes, but I'm just confirming). If your load balancer is public, then its DNS record should be returning public IPs (either AWS managed or elastic), not belonging to any VPC subnet.

Comment: @Quassnoi NLB is public, yes. The NLB has a DNS record, when I do a lookup this DNS record has 2 public IPs (assigned by AWS, not elastic). I am running one instance of my Fargate service. This randomly gets placed in subnet A or subnet B. When I make a request I hit my NLB and it resolves to one of the the public IPs. It appears that each public IP is then mapped to the internal subnets. So the resolution of the DNS resolves to the public IP not associated with the subnet where my service is running then I get a timeout. Does that help clarify?

Comment: @iqueqiorio the doc you cited is about ALB, where cross-zone load balancing is on by default.  For NLB, it isn't, and you definitely need it on in this scenario.

Answer (score 1):

From the discussion in the comments, I understand that you have just one Fargate target that is on and off, and every time it's being created in different availability zones.

EC2 will periodically check health of targets in the target group. If there are no healthy targets in a zone, NLB will remove the IP address bound to this zone from the public DNS record.

If there are no healthy targets in any availability zone, NLB will return all registered addresses in all zones, and hope for the best. This is what will happen during the outage, when your task is being re-run.

This requires cooperation from the client and its DNS provider(s), because the stale DNS record can get cached at multiple points on its way from AWS to the client's network library.

If your target moves from one zone to another, and you want to avoid (or, rather, minimize) interruptions in your service, you can make NLB work for your setup by [enabling cross-zone load balancing](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticloadbalancing/latest/network/network-load-balancers.html#cross-zone-load-balancing) (and paying for cross-AZ network transfer if your client hits the wrong zone).

However, if you truly don't want interruptions, you should create at least one instance in each availaibility zone, and make sure that at least one instance is always running and responding to health checks.